# Visual Studio themes with Resharper support?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Does anyone have any good font and colour themes for Visual Studio that will give me nice support for Resharper? The majority of themes out there don't support Resharper, and as such all the extra R# highlighting looks rubbish...

Cheers!
Matt

Answer (score 3):

I use this [VibrantInk](http://www.iunknown.com/2007/06/vibrant_ink_vis.html) theme, with [EnvyCode R](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/05/26/envy-code-r-preview-7-coding-font-released) font, looks good with the Resharper Highlighting

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.muonlab.com/2009/05/14/visual-studio-and-resharper-colour-woes-with-added-visual-svn/) are mine, based on textmate

Edit: (still a work in progress, but its getting there)